# Custom TypeORM errors in NestJS Service

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am playing around with `NestJS` and I would like to take the error thrown from `TypeORM` and convert it into a shape that I can control.

Right now, I'm just trying to catch the error thrown from `TypeORM` and log it out to see that my custom filter is working correctly. But unfortunately, my `console.log` statement in the filter is never logging.

Here is a slimmed down version of my service and filter

user.service.ts

```js
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Users)
    private readonly userRepository: Repository<Users>,
  ) {}

  @UseFilters(new TypeOrmFilter())
  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    const user = this.userRepository.create(createUserDto);
    return this.userRepository.save(user);
  }
}
```

type-orm-filter.ts

```js
@Catch()
export class TypeOrmFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    console.log('\nI have caught an error\n', exception);
    throw exception;
  }
}
```

Here is the log output from the error being thrown by `TypeORM`

```sh
[Nest] 61496   - 04/11/2021, 9:01:42 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] invalid input syntax for type uuid: "123e4567" +2482ms
QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "123e4567"
    at new QueryFailedError (my-nest-project/error-project-nestjs/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (my-nest-project/error-project-nestjs/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:247:31)
    at step (my-nest-project/error-project-nestjs/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.throw (my-nest-project/error-project-nestjs/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at rejected (my-nest-project/error-project-nestjs/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: what if you use pipes instead? like https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#exception-mapping it will map a typeorm error to another one

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `await` in `UserService#create` :p

tip: If you configure ESLint properly, this might never happen again because you already marked that method with `await` (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await). Or just enforce typing the return (https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v3.10.1/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  Same situation.  The `create` method doesn't return a promise either.  The method signature is `create(entityLike: DeepPartial<Entity>): Entity;` unlike `save` which does return a promise `save<T extends DeepPartial<Entity>>(entity: T, options?: SaveOptions): Promise<T & Entity>;`

Comment: oh right! I've misunderstand that due to the `async` usage with no `await` : /
Since your filter is acting like a catch-everything one, I didn't understant why this isn't working